# Javascript object constructor setting as undefined

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, undefined

I've created a new object, and in that object I have several object variables, but the events (optional) object isn't being set correctly. It's coming up as undefined when called in the build function by the event tab, and my guess it's something to do with it possibly being asynchronous. Below is my object and call, and also what I'm getting when referencing the object.

I can't figure out why exactly it's coming in as undefined as it's being set before the build function is even called.

UPDATE: This fiddle has the exact code as being called. https://jsfiddle.net/trickell/Leg1gqkz/2/

The problem is in the checkEvents() method.

```
var Wizard = function(id, events) {
  this.activeTab  = '';
  this.prevTab    = '';
  this.nextTab    = '';
  this.events     = (events) ? events : {}; // Optional events object. User may define events based on tab. (ex. "tabName" : function(){})

  console.log(this.events);  // Returns object with no keys

  this.build(id);
  return this;
}

Wizard.prototype.build = function(id){
  var tab = id,
      events = this.events;

  // **** This is what's showing up as undefined!!! *****/
  console.log(events.cardInfo);  
}

(function($, undefined){

  var wiz  = new Wizard($('#package_wizard'),
    {
        cardInfo : function() {
            alert('hello world');
        }
    });

 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're missing a semicolon after your definition for `build`. Without a semicolon, you're essentially doing this:

```
Wizard.prototype.build = function() {
  // do stuff
}(function($, undefined) { ... })();
```

Meaning, you're trying to call the function *immediately* and pass it a function as an argument. Here's your code with semicolons in the right places.

```js
var Wizard = function(id, events) {
  console.log(events);
  this.activeTab = '';
  this.prevTab = '';
  this.nextTab = '';
  this.events = (events) ? events : {}; // Optional events object. User may define events based on tab. (ex. "tabName" : function(){})

  console.log(this.events); // Returns object with no keys

  this.build(id);
  return this;
}; // <-- Here's a semicolon

Wizard.prototype.build = function(id) {
  var tab = id,
    events = this.events;

  // **** This is what's showing up as undefined!!! *****/
  console.log(events.cardInfo);
}; // <-- and the original problem

(function($, undefined) {

  var wiz = new Wizard($('#package_wizard'), {
    cardInfo: function() {
      alert('hello world');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

--

As for your update, the problem is you have a typo. You wrote

```
event.cardInfo()
```

when you should have written

```
events.cardInfo()
```

Comment: I'm not exactly defining it like that. I'm using the $.extend(Wizard.prototype, { build: function(){} }); method from jquery.

Comment: @jamadri Then show your exact code. As you can see, that was the problem in this case. If you're doing something else and this doesn't solve it, I need to see that code.

Comment: I'm going to modify this with a fiddle URL with the entire widget I've created. Maybe it will shed some light on exactly what's happening xD

Comment: @jamadri When reducing the example, make sure the outcome doesn't change, and that the same problem can be observed. Right now, you've received an answer to the question as it was asked, please don't make edits to the question that would invalidate the answers you were given. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, as Mike said your are calling that method with the IFEE and that's make the `this` to be `Window`... put the `semicolon` where needed

Comment: I've updated it with the full code in the JSFiddle. I'm not exactly sure where i'm falling short here.

Comment: Thanks @MadaraUchiha. I'll ask a new question!

Comment: @jamadri I found your problem.

Comment: @MikeC, I'll link you to the new question, or would it be easier for you to answer via here? (Just saw you updated your answer! Thanks!)

Comment: @jamadri Did you check my update? The answer is at the bottom.